# About the jump of action in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Now I have an action A and an action B,I want to jump to action B in action A.But action B has
a parameter "MyModel".If I write like this:

```
public ActionResult A(MyModel model)
{
  ...
  return B(model);
}

public ActionResult B(MyModel model)
{
  ...
  return View();
}
```

It will cause an error.

What should I do to transfer the parameter "MyModel" to action B in action A?

Comment: This causes an error?? Are you sure? It shouldn't. Your problem must be located elsewhere...

Comment: Try return B(model, "B");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
public ActionResult A(MyModel model)
{

  return RedirectToAction("B", model);
}
```

Comment: It causes an NullReferenceException

Comment: I made a mistake.I write like this: return RedirectToAction("B",new { model = model });          Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult A(MyModel model)
{
  ...
  TempData["object"] = new { Model= model };
  return RedirectToAction("B");
}
```

Then in your `B` action

```
public ActionResult B(MyModel model)
{
  ...
var yourObj = TempData["object"];
    model=yourObj .Model;
  return View();
}
```